# Does anyone remember a YA fantasy novel with a wizard certificate in the back?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, wizards, witches

I can't remember much about it but I believe it was something that told a story about becoming a wizard or something to that nature.  I keep thinking it's So You Want to Be a Wizard but that's sitting on my shelf and isn't it.  At the end of the book there was this whole ritual thing and a mail-in form you could send to get an official wizard certification or something like that.  It even involved finding a staff and feathers and all sorts of witchcraft-like practices that were set up more for kids.  I probably read the story in the early 2000's but I don't know when it was published.

Comment: I wonder if this wasn't only in the hard cover first edition of *So You Want to be a Wizard*?

Comment: I have no way to check that unfortunately.  As it is, I don't recognize the first edition hardcover's art so I don't know.

Comment: That, at least, [we can fix](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?224789).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is likely to be [The Book of Wizardry: The Apprentice's Guide to the Secrets of the Wizards' Guild](https://archive.org/details/bookofwizardry00corn), published in 2003.

> Tongue-in-cheek and deliciously droll, "Cornelius Rumstuckle" is the
> fictional narrator of The Book of Wizardry. Now featuring a new cover,
> this highly entertaining guide to wizardry makes genuine magical ideas
> accessible to young adults.
>
> Brennan's fun wizard training manual is filled with interactive
> activities: how to make a wand and other wizard tools, discover your
> Wizard's name, switch on Wizard's Power, read the future in the
> Wizard's Oracle, and more. Those who successfully complete the
> Wizard's Adventure and crack the code in this book can become an
> accredited member of the Wizard's Guild.

I read this as a child, probably shortly after publication, and specifically remember one of the tasks involving collecting feathers.

Comment: This looks insanely familiar, going to do a bit more research before I accept but I think this might be it!

Comment: This was definitely it!  In fact I even found an article talking about it as well as other books that influenced someone in learning witchcraft as a child!  https://www.patheos.com/blogs/byathameandstang/2018/05/5-books-of-influenced-my-craft-as-a-child/
It straight up states that if you complete the adventure in the book you could have the "guild" send a packet of cool shit.  It's not a mail in form at the back of the book like I thought but it's hidden in the adventure.

PS: It really doesn't help that they put "So you want to be a wizard?" on the back of the book lol

Comment: I very nearly wrote up a story identification question about this book a few years ago, so your question was like déjà vu. I'd found it by myself at the time because I had vague memories of the name 'Cornelius' and that was enough for Google to help me out.